# using .to_period() to get end of business month in python

Tags: python, pandas

I say a post that allowed me to get month end in an dataframe index but it only provided Calendar month end and I wanted BUSINESS month end

```
df_mth_return.index = df_mth_return.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')
df_mth_return
```

this is a snipit of my resulting data frame.  So you can see that 2/29/1992 should be 2/28/1992 and 5/31/1992 and 5/28/1992 and it continues on

```
            IBM US Equity   MMM US Equity
Date    
2/29/1992   -2.174845   0.878127
3/31/1992   -3.884848   -2.470764
4/30/1992   8.682919    5.634692
5/31/1992   1.312976    2.867628
6/30/1992   7.85108     1.435327
```

I tried to period ('BM' and it threw and error and other post suggested pd.offset but that did not work either.

Can anyone suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `BMonthEnd` with `date_range`

```
In [28]: pd.date_range('19920101', '19920630', freq=dt.BMonthEnd())
Out[28]:
DatetimeIndex(['1992-01-31', '1992-02-28', '1992-03-31', '1992-04-30',
               '1992-05-29', '1992-06-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM', tz=None)
```